# Webpage is not updating after Ajax call to controller with new data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I was creating a post method to display new data after a datepicker selection in jquery. The jquery method is working and I can loop through the new data in the view but it is not displaying in the browser. Here is my post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Birthdays(DateTime? pickedDate = null)
{
    if (pickedDate == null)
    {
        startDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        startDate = (DateTime)pickedDate;
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    List<OKSwingMemberList> birthdayList = db.OKSwingMemberLists.ToList();
    ViewBag.birthDayList = birthdayList.Where(b => b.BirthMonth == startDate.Month.ToString()).Where(a => a.Anniversary > DateTime.Now).OrderBy(o => o.LastName);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewbag is only loaded at the time of page load (on the server) and ajax is designed for client side rendering.  You'll need to pass back your data via json instead of in the Viewbag:

Something like:

```
birthdayList = birthdayList.Where(b => b.BirthMonth == startDate.Month.ToString()).Where(a => a.Anniversary > DateTime.Now).OrderBy(o => o.LastName))
return Json(new {BirthdayList = birthdayList});
```

And then access it in the js with something like:

```
success: function (data) {
    var bithdayList = data.BirthdayList;
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give that a try. Thank you...still got a lot to learn.